# Capture microphone in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio, blob, getusermedia

I need to capture microphone audio in IE10. So far I have two semi-working solutions:

- getUserMedia from Microsoft's experimental WebRTC plugin: 
  http://www.html5labs.com/prototypes/media-capture-api-(2nd-updated)/media-capture-api-(2nd-update)/info
  The issue with this is that while I can capture and replay the audio in the browser, I cannot send the audio to the server. In particular, it is not clear how to extract the audio data from the "blob" object:

  ```
  function msStopRecordCallback(blob) {
        console.log(blob) // outputs {}
        console.dir(blob) // outputs {}

        playMediaObject.Play(blob); // This works!

  }
  ```
- jRecorder: http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery The issue with this is that it relies on Flash to capture the audio, which is something I would like to avoid.

Are there any other ways to capture audio in IE10?

Comment: No; you need to use a plugin, and you've identified two valid choices.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that my answer a bit late, but...
You may upload a blob to a server as following (Javascript):

```
function saveBlob(blob)
{
   var uploader = new CustomXMLHttpRequest();
   uploader.onpartreceived = function (response)
   {
     // TODO: handle the server response here
   };

   var base = window.location.toString();
   var uploadService = base.substr(0, base.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/api/upload";

   uploader.open("POST", uploadService, true);

   uploader.responseType = "text";

   var form = new FormData();
   form.append("fname", blob, "audio.wav");

   uploader.send(form);
}
```

On the server side, you may treat this blob as a file attachment, e.g. (C#):

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
   {
      // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
      if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
      {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
      }

      var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
      var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

      try
      {
        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        var fileName = "";

        // get the uploaded files.
        foreach (var data in provider.FileData)
        {
          var file = new FileInfo(data.LocalFileName);

          // TODO: handle received file here
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      }
      catch (System.Exception e)
      {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
      }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.